# Enterprise architect - Compare baseline changes

Tags: compare, enterprise-architect, baseline

I would like to know, what tool or extension to use to compare changes between two baselines in Enterprise architect (EA). 
Default tool what EA provides, does not work with HTML tags at all. 
If text in changed element is larger, it starts to be very difficult to compare differences.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any third-party baseline diff tool, and neither the GUI nor the API provide the option of plugging in a separate tool to do comparisons.

This would be a useful enhancement, so I suggest you post it to Sparx as a feature suggestion.